# Model building methodology

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

I happen to have a dataset of 4000 rows, where the target variable has 3999 1's and only one 0.

It is a quarterly data, and I'm supposed to calculate the probability of success in the next quarter. Is it feasible to apply logistic regression here?

Or can somebody provide me a better alternative?

Comment: You mean dataset is so unbalanced (One example of false and all the other true)?

Comment: How many features do you have?

Comment: @DavidS1992 yes very unbalanced. I have around 20 to 25 independent variables/features.

Comment: With such unbalanced data you are probably better off using one-class classifiers and see the negative class as outlier. Also, can you define "probability of success"?

Comment: Do you have a link where I can look up python codes based on one class classifier? By probability I mean chances of 1's occurring in the next quarter as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the dataset is too unbalanced. The one negative example can not be statistically significant. Also, you can't do cross-validation so you can't even validate your model.

You can try to visualize data in lower dimension to check if the negative example is clearly the outlier. You can look for the 'anomaly detection' topic to find out more.

However you'll not find the answer if the 1's will occur in the next quarter, because the data is not correct for that. With such data, if you could have more negative examples, you could predict what will be the label of next, new sample, with given features. And that is not the answer what will be probability of similar dataset occurring in the next quarter.